# React-jss doesn't update even if the jss instance updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss, react-lifecycle

So, an app should be rendered `rtl` or `ltr` depending on its state.

I have created a sandbox to demonstrate what should be done: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/rr8lyw3op4?fontsize=14

You can see that the checked state property enables or disables `RTL`. However, if you change its value, `JssProvider` doesn't seem to figure that out and it keeps its configuration with how the initial value was.

I do think that should be possible, but don't know what's wrong!! Any ideas?